# Problem with the developing of the function

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I'm trying to develop the real function $f(x) = (1 + x)^{\alpha}$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, but I'm stuck in the middle.

**What I did until now:**

First, we have that the $f$ is defined for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then, I examined if the $f$ is infinitely diferentiable:

$$f'(x) = \alpha(1 + x)^{\alpha - 1},$$

$$f'(x) = \alpha(\alpha - 1)(1 + x)^{\alpha - 2},$$

$$f'''(x) = \alpha(\alpha - 1)(\alpha - 2)(1 + x)^{\alpha - 3},$$

$$\vdots$$

$$f^{(n)}(x) = \alpha(\alpha - 1)(\alpha - 2) \cdots (\alpha - n + 1)(1 + x)^{\alpha - n}.$$

So, $f$ is infinitely diferentiable on the whole set $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, I chose the point $x_0 = 0$ in which we are going to develop $f$.

Because, $f$ is infinitely diferentiable, that implies it's also continuous with all its derivatives up to the $n$-th order and in the $n$-th order, in the arbitrarily neighborhood $U$ of the point $x_0 = 0$, and it has derivative of the $n + 1$-st order in $x_0$. So, now we have that all conditions of the following theorem,

[Checking my understanding of the process of developing function into power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162217/checking-my-understanding-of-the-process-of-developing-function-into-power-serie),

are fulfilled. Now we have that we can write MacLaurien formula for the $f$ (because $x_0 = 0$):

$$f(x) = f(0) + \frac{f'(0)}{1!}x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{3!}x^3 + \cdots + \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n + R_n(x) = $$

$$= 1 + \frac{\alpha x}{1!} + \frac{\alpha(\alpha - 1) x^2}{2!} + \frac{\alpha(\alpha - 1)(\alpha - 2) x^3}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{\alpha \cdots (\alpha - n + 1) x^n}{n!} + R_n(x) =$$

$$= 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha(\alpha - 1) \cdots (\alpha - n + 1) x^n}{n!} + R_n(x).$$

**My question:**

I think that is a mistake that I have $1$ in the last row of the last equation. I don't think that it can be added to the remainder $R_n(x)$.

Please, could you tell me where I made a mistake and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Tuck it into your series by making it $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$

Since your sum is effectively $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom \alpha n x^n$$ setting $n=0$ gives the $1$ you took out.

Comment: So, $\n \choose k$ can use real numbers? I know it is defined using factorial and factorial is defined only in $\mathbb{N}$. I never saw this before.

Comment: If I only use $\alpha \choose k$ as a mark for $\frac{\alpha(\alpha - 1)\cdots(\alpha - n + 1)}{n!}$ and not binomial coefficient, I think I would get $\alpha + 1$ for $n = 0$.

Comment: They are the same thing: $$\alpha(\alpha-1)\ldots(\alpha-(n-1))=\alpha^{\underline{\alpha-n}}=\frac{\alpha!}{(\alpha-n)!}$$ Multiplying this by $\frac{1}{n!}$ gives $$\binom{\alpha}{n}=\frac{\alpha!}{n!(\alpha-n)!}$$

Comment: All I'm saying is that plugging $n=0$ into your sum would give $1$. Notice that you have a term being $$f^{(n)}(x)= (1+x)^{\alpha-n}\cdot\prod_{t=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-t)$$ When $n=0, x=0$, the product has no terms so you just get $(1+0)^\alpha=1$